# What does `module.exports.instance` means?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sometimes I've seen people use `module.exports.instance` in their code ([example](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets/blob/master/src/assets.coffee#L32)). How does this differ from `module.exports`?

Comment: It's a property being added to the `exports` object, just like any other property. They're assigning an instance of the `ConnectAssets` constructor to it. Nothing special really. It has no special meaning WRT NodeJS API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal difference is that `module.exports.instance` is a property of the object referenced by `module.exports`.

Why use a property named `instance`? One possibility is an application of the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to [resolve issues with circular dependencies among modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872988/161152).

Comment: So that I can require that module and attache new property to that module? For instance, `var connectAssets = require('connect-assets'); connectAssets.instance.foo = 'bar';`

Comment: You can assign any valid property you'd like to a module. For example `var module = require('module'); module.foo = 'bar';` Using `instance` as a property name has no special meaning and it is treated like any other property of the object. I was just giving an example of where you might use a property named `instance`.