# Typescript Inheritance across CommonJS modules - Circular Dependencies

Tags: inheritance, typescript, commonjs

I cannot get inheritance to work across CommonJS modules generated using typescript 1.0 (`tsc`is run using `--module commonjs`)

This fails when two classes inheriting the same base class, call each other "through" the base class.

What seems to hapeen is that the first class imports the Base Class, which imports the second class which also imports the Base Class but the last Base Class import is failing.

An example illustrating this behaviour is provided below.

**Is there anything in the Typescript or the CommonJS specifications preventing me from doing this, or is this a bug ?**

=== Example ===

This fascinating piece of software is failed by running `Lower.test.ts`. What it simply tries to achieve is loading a word into `Lower` which keeps it in lower case, then using the inherited `toUpper()` method from the `Base` class, transforms it in upper case using the `Upper` class (which also inherits `Base`)

Lower.test.ts

```
import Lower = require('./Lower')

console.log(new Lower('smallcaps').toUpper())
```

Base.ts

```
import Upper = require('./Upper')

class Base {

    word: string

    toUpper(): string {
        return new Upper(this.word).word
    }
}

export = Base
```

Upper.ts

```
import Base = require('./Base')

class Upper extends Base {

    constructor(word:string) {
        super()
        this.word = word.toUpperCase()
    }
}

export = Upper
```

Lower.ts

```
import Base = require('./Base')

class Lower extends Base {

    constructor(word:string) {

        super()
        this.word = word.toLowerCase()
    }
}

export = Lower
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and testing, this ends up being a case of circular dependencies.

The issue is pretty well documented and various solutions have been proposed:

1. Exporting before `requiring`: [here](https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg)
2. Delaying the `require` or using injection: [here](http://tomkit.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/circular-dependencies-dependency-injection-in-node-js/)
3. Moving statements around: a pretty long list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/nodejs-module-dependency-issue)

Unfortunately, there is very little control on where `import` and `export` statements can be set in Typescript which reduces solutions to injection only. The rewritten `Base` class is provided below.

Circular dependencies are a pain in Javascript modular projects. Typescript somehow makes things worse. That is bad news for a language supposed to address large projects

**EDIT**
I have opened a case and submitted a proposed transpiler fix to the TypeScript project: [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2613)

Base.ts

```
//This import will "fail" by importing an empty object but is needed to trick the compiler
//An alternative is to design and Upper.d.ts definition file and reference it
import Upper = require('./Upper')

class Base {

    //Upper is a sub-class of Base and needs to be injected to be instantiated
    private _Upper: typeof Upper

    word: string

    constructor(_Upper: typeof Upper) {
        this._Upper = _Upper
    }

    toUpper(): string {
        //This where the injection is used
        return new this._Upper(this.word).word
    }


    getUpperWord(upper: Upper): string {
        //The injection is not reauired in this case
        return upper.word
    }
}

export = Base
```

Upper.ts

```
import Base = require('./Base')

class Upper extends Base {

    constructor(word:string) {
        super(Upper)
        this.word = word.toUpperCase();
    }
}

export = Upper
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to depend in just one direction - as per SOLID principles.

However, as you always need both `Base` and `Upper` (i.e. you cannot have one without the other) you can add them to the same module...

base.ts

```
export class Base {
    word: string

    toUpper(): string {
        return new Upper(this.word).word
    }
}

export class Upper extends Base {

    constructor(word: string) {
        super()
        this.word = word.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

lower.ts

```
import b = require('base')

class Lower extends b.Base {

    constructor(word: string) {

        super()
        this.word = word.toLowerCase()
    }
}

export = Lower
```

app.ts

```
import Lower = require('lower');

console.log(new Lower('smallcaps').toUpper());
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround; I can live with the fact that it reduces modularity but it still leaves the question open though. As for going in one direction, it does not always make sense: imagine this very simple geometry app that implements a `Vector`. A `Vector` can scale by multiplying it by another `Vector`, like many other geometric figures. It makes sense to create a `Scalable` class, that `Vector` inherits, and which implements a `scale()` method which has a `Vector` as argument. Here you go: inheritance of a class that uses one of its sub-classes in a method.

Comment: I would still avoid it. If a Vector can always scale, why is Scalable a sub class. If it can't always scale, it shouldn't have a scale method, the scale method should be added by the Scalable sub class.