# MongooseJS prehook 'remove' cyclical dependency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, requirejs

There is a one to many relationship between schemaA and schemaB. If I call schemaA.remove(); I want all related schemaB to be removed. If I call schemaB.remove() I want the reference to schemaB in instanceA to be removed.

Using

```
SchemaA
  .pre('remove', function (next) {
    var instanceBIdArray = this.instanceBIdArray;

    async.map(instanceBIdArray, function (instanceBId, callback) {
        SchemaB.findByIdAndRemove(instanceBId, function (err, instanceB) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          if (!instanceB) callback('instanceB not found.');
          callback(null, instanceBId);
        });
      },
      function (err, results) {
        if (err) next(new Error('Something went wrong with deleting instanceB.'));
        return next();
      });
  });
```

And

```
SchemaB
  .pre('remove', function (next) {
    var self = this;
    SchemaA.findByIdAndUpdate(self.instanceAId, {
      $pull: {
        instanceBIdArray: self._id
      }
    }, function (err, instanceA) {
      if (err) next(new Error('Something went wrong with deleting instanceA.'));
      return next();
    });
  });
```

in each of the mongoose schemas respectively seems to be the right way to approach this. However, I can only get one of the two to work. If I have both express will not compile, and it will say that schemaB does not exist.

I believe this has something to do with require.js and that in order to export schemaA requirejs needs to export schemaB and vice versa. Any insight to this is greatly appreciated!

The error is: `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "A".`

Comment: What's your actual code? (in place of the pseudo code)

Comment: Sounds like you have a dependency cycle in your code; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js) for ideas on how to deal with it.

Comment: I've been attempting these solutions, but since mongoose needs to compile the Schemas in the end it keeps giving me the MissingSchemaError

Comment: Even if I put these schemas in the same JS file, I don't think I can compile both mongoose schemas...

Comment: Instead of using the schema variable, use `mongoose.model('A').findByIdAndUpdate`, where `A` is the model name associated to `SchemaA`. As long as both models have been registered before you attempt to save one of the documents it will work.

Comment: Ah that seems like a good solution I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hey I just tried out this solution and it works very nicely. Thank you @BrianShamblen