# why there is type error in require in when sending nav in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

app.js:

```
const adminRouter = require('./src/routes/adminRoutes')(nav);
```

routes.js:

```
function Router(nav){
    adminRouter.route('/')
    .get((req,res)=>{
        res.send('inserting books');
    });

    return adminRouter;
}

module.export = Router;
```

error:

```
const adminRouter = require('./src/routes/adminRoutes')(nav);
                                                   ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

it's showing error in the nav and have no clue why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function) SO question?

Answer (score 1):

Your **routes.js** module should use `module.exports`, plural:

```
module.exports = Router;
```