# Passport JS -> require(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am getting this error when I try to run the server, trying a require for Passport module.

Passport JS  ->  require(...) is not a function

```
const passport = require('passport');


require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

UPDATED
Here the passport file

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const User = require('../app/models/user');

module.export = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        })
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'El email ya existe'));
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.local.email = email;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) { throw err; }
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            })
        }));

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'El email no ha sido encontrado'));
                }
                if (!user.validatePassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password'));
                }
                return done(null, user);
            })
        }));
}
```

Comment: What type of error you get in your console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because it thinks you are trying to invoke a function hense your error. `is not a function`

it requires the passport module and try to invoke it with passport var as an arg.

import passport as a constant,

`const passport = require('passport');`

**UPDATED ANSWER**

it seems
you are trying to import `'./config/passport'` which probably doesn't resolve to a function please refer to
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33008076/1283672)

**UPDATED ANSWER #2**

seems like you have a typo . try changing `module.export` to `module.exports` in your passport custom module

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it is already done, I took for granted. Still not working

Comment: @VictorSegovia could you post `'./config/passport'` ?

Comment: @VictorSegovia try writing `module.exports` instead of `module.export`

Answer (score 5):

Implement this it will might help.

```
const passport=require("passport");
```