# Node require is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/implementing-json-web-tokens-passport-js-in-a-javascript-application-with-react-b86b1f313436). I am changing existing AWS Lambda based app to NodeJS Express app.

server.js imports the module and executes it passing the Express app as an argument:

```
require('./handlers/getStatus')(app);
```

The module is trivial, it exports a function with single argument

```
exports = app => {
    app.get('/v1/status', (req, res) => {
        console.log("handler starts");
        const response = {
            api: '1.0',
            status: 'OK'
        };
        return res.send(response);
    });
};
```

When I run this app with Node v13.11.0, there is an error:

```
node server.js
C:\dev\mezinamiridici\infrastructure\src\server.js:5
require('./handlers/getStatus')(app);                               ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\mezinamiridici\infrastructure\src\server.js:5:32)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
```

Why? Thank you

Comment: try to use module.exports instead of exports

Answer (score 1):

use

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/v1/status', (req, res) => {
        console.log("handler starts");
        const response = {
            api: '1.0',
            status: 'OK'
        };
        return res.send(response);
    });
};
```

you will similar answer here 
[NodeJs : TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Hmm, I tried it originally and I had an error that module has no property exports. But it works now. WebStorm stil complains this way