# const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes) - TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am beginner in web dev and trying to create a project using Mysql, Node.js with Express. Facing this TypeError issue while using Sequalize. Can someone please explain it to me and help me find a solution?

> "sequelize": "^6.19.0"

> "sequelize-cli": "^6.4.1"

> 

/models/user.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  return user;
};
```

> 

/models/index.js:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../../config/config.js`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

> 

error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./src/api/server.js`
/home/back-end/src/models/index.js:25
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
                                                     ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at /home/back-end/src/models/index.js:25:54
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/back-end/src/models/index.js:24:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/back-end/src/services/usersService.js:1:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs : TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

**From experience**, I encountered this after I added a file that is not a model in the 'models' directory. Supposedly one can only add model files to the 'models' directory, as index.js checks every file in the whole directory.

Answer (score -1):

I have actually been struggling with this problem for a while now. What worked for me is that I used the ES6 class referred to as (extend Model in the Sequelize documentation) to create my table instead of the (Sequelize.define). I am honestly still not sure why, but you can find how to create a table in sequelize with the Extend Model in the Sequelize documentation.

Answer (score -1):

In your index.js file, You should just use this format and it will solve your error

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database, 
  config.username, 
  config.password, 
  config
);   

fs
 .readFileSync(__dirname)
 .filter((file) =>
  file !== 'index.js'
 )
.forEach((file) => {
   const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes)
    db[model.name] = model
 })
 
 db.sequelize = sequelize
 db.Sequelize = Sequelize

 module.exports = db
```

Answer (score -1):

As @farajael alluded to, one of your files in the `/models` directory is not defining a model correctly. Eg a completely commented out file in this directory will cause this error to occur.

You can debug which file is causing the issue by adding a console.log in the `forEach loop`:

```
  .forEach(file => {
    console.log("FILE IS ",file);
    model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

Then restart your server, look at the server logs, and the last "FILE IS" statement before the crash is the problem.