# Error message keeps appearing even tho there is a file dedicated to that code - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So i have been trying to fix this issue for a while now and even rewrote some bits but so far it still keeps giving the same thing... Below is the code and the terminal output
This is done using node.js and discord.js

**Main Bot Code**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { token } = process.env;
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.color = "";
client.commandarray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles)
    require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handleEvents();
client.handleCommands();
client.login(token);
```

**The Terminal Output**

```
C:\Users\Maheel\Desktop\NewTestingBOt\src\bot.js:17
    require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
                                            ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maheel\Desktop\NewTestingBOt\src\bot.js:17:45)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Thanks in advance to those who help with this error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs : TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that what your exporting from that file is a function, and not an object.

function:

```js
module.exports = (param) => {
    console.log("hello world")
}
```

object:

```js
module.exports = {
    helloWorld: () => {
        console.log("hello world")
    }
}
```