# require("connect-redis")(session); require(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, backend, express-session, ioredis, connect-redis

I was building a real-time chat app. I am using express-session to add cookies so that users don't have to login every time page refreshes.

```
const session = require("express-session");
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);
```

This is my import. I have more but I think these are related to the problem so I am sharing only these. And I have all of this downloader in my project in case anyone says to double check if I installed them properly or not that's why I am adding this. This is how I was implementing the code ...

```
const redisClient = new Redis();
app.use(session({
    secret:process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    credentials:true,
    name:"$id",
    store: new RedisStore({client:redisClient}), //This is the user's session information
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    cookie: {
        secure:process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "production" ? "true" : "auto",
        httpOnly:true,
        expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        sameSite:process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
    }
}))
```

But I keep this error message that require(...) is not a function. I tried to solve it but I couldn't.

I tried to install redis instead of ioredis to see if this solves but it did not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs : TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I checked the express-session in the node modules. And it is class. I cannot change it to function because everything will break.

Answer (score 1):

The npm page for `connect-redis` says to use .default instead of (session) when you require the `RedisStore`:

```
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default
```

After I used default everything spun up properly