# NodeJS some modules not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a game with socket.io and nodejs, and I'm making a module called rooms.js, this module require `users.js` module and `fiveSocket.js` module
but when I call `Rooms.New` from the main server file, it says that `fiveSocket` is undefined, same problem when `Rooms.New` calls a `users.js` function, I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSocketIDbyId' of undefined`

**rooms.js:**

```
var mysql   = require('../mysql/mysql.js');
var headers = require('./headers.js');
var users   = require('./users.js');
var fiveSocket = require('./sockets.js');
var Rooms = {
    Obj: {},
    Room: function(data) {
        var room = this;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.users = [];
        this.floorCode = data.floor;
        this.description = data.desc;
        this.maxUsers = data.maxUsers;
        this.owner = data.owner;
        this.setTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.dbID = data.dbID;
        this.doorx = data.doorx;
        this.doory = data.doory;
        this.doordir = data.doordir;
    },
    New: function(socketID, roomID) {
        var keys      = Object.keys(Rooms.Obj).length;
        var id        = keys + 1;
        var callback  = function(row) {
            fiveSocket.emitClient(socketID, headers.roomData, {
                title: row.title,
                desc: row.description,
                mapStr: row.floorCode,
                doorx: row.doorx,
                doory: row.doory,
                doordir: row.doordir
            });
            var uid = users.getIdBySocketID(socketID);
            users.Obj[uid].curRoom = roomID;
            var rid = Rooms.getIdByDbID(roomID);
            Rooms.Obj[rid].users.push(uid);
        }
        if(Rooms.getIdByDbID(roomID) != false) {
            var room = Rooms.getIdByDbID(roomID);
            var row = { title: room.name, description: room.description, floorCode: room.foorCode, doorx: room.doorx, doory: room.doory, doordir: room.doordir };
            callback(row);
        } else {
            mysql.Query('SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1', roomID, function(rows) {
                if(rows.length > 0) {
                    var row = rows[0];
                    Rooms.Obj[id] = new Rooms.Room({name: row.title, floorCode: row.floorCode, desc: row.description, maxUsers: row.maxUsers, owner: row.owner, dbID: row.id, doorx: row.doorx, doory: row.doory, doordir: row.doordir});
                    callback(row);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    removeUser: function(DBroomID, userID) {
        var rid = Rooms.getIdByDbID(DBroomID);
        var room = Rooms.Obj[rid];
        var index = room.indexOf(userID);
        if (index > -1) array.splice(index, 1);
    },
    Listener: function(users) {
        setInterval(function(){
            for(var roomID in Rooms.Obj) {
                var room = Rooms.Obj[roomID];
                // send users coordinates 
                room.users.forEach(function(uid) {
                    var socketID = users.getSocketIDbyId(uid);
                    var data = Rooms.getUsersInRoomData(roomID);
                    fiveSocket.emitClient(socketID, headers.roomUsers, data);
                });
                // unload inactive rooms (no users after 10 seconds)
                var activeUsers = room.users.length;
                var timestamp = room.setTime;
                var t = new Date(); t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);
                var time2 = t.getTime();
                if(activeUsers <= 0 && timestamp < time2) {
                    Rooms.Remove(roomID);
                }
            }
        }, 1);
    },
    getUsersInRoomData: function(roomID) {
        var room = Rooms.Obj[roomID];
        var obj = {};
        room.users.forEach(function(uid) {
            var user = users.Obj[uid];  
            obj[uid] = {
                username: user.username,
                position: user.position,
                figure: user.figure
            };
        });
        return obj;
    },
    Remove: function(id) {
        delete Rooms.Obj[id];
    },
    getIdByDbID: function(dbID) {
        var result = null;
        for(var room in Rooms.Obj) {
            var u = Rooms.Obj[room]; 
            if(u.dbID == dbID) var result = room;
        }
        if(result == null) return false;
        else return result;
    },
    getDbIDbyId: function(id) {
        return Rooms.Obj[id].dbID;
    }
}
Rooms.Listener();
module.exports = Rooms;
```

*EDIT: (if it can be helpful)*
**When I console.log fiveSocket on the main file**
[image]

**When I console.log fiveSocket on the `rooms.js` file**
[image]

> EDIT2: When I've removed `var users = require('./users.js');` from `fiveSocket`, when I `console.log` it in `rooms.js` it works, why ?
>   
> EDIT3: I still have the problem

If you need the others modules sources:
**Users.JS:**  http://pastebin.com/Ynq9Qvi7 
**sockets.JS** http://pastebin.com/wpmbKeAA

Comment: Are you requiring fivesocket the same way in other files that work? Also are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes the same way, The path is correct beacause it's in the same directory (rooms.js and fiveSocket.js are in the same directory)

Comment: Is fivesocket a functional object? Like something you'd have to call new on?

Comment: Before you define Room, try to log fiveSocket and see if the issue is with your require

Comment: When I console.log on rooms.js, here's the result http://i.imgur.com/vnc6QU5.png

Comment: And when I console.log it on the main file, here's the result http://i.imgur.com/OuuuIRb.png

Comment: That's so weird that they have different outputs

Comment: When I've removed `var users = require('./users.js');` from `fiveSockets.js`, when I console.log it in rooms.js it works, why ?

Comment: It could be in your Listener function if excluding users worked.

Comment: @christopherclark when I've commented the line Rooms.Listener(); everything worked like magic, what's wrong with Rooms.Listener ?

Comment: The problem is likely a parsing error in your `users.js` file. Can you share the source for `users.js`?

Comment: @gnerkus http://pastebin.com/Ynq9Qvi7

Comment: EDIT: I still have the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rooms" requires "Users" and vice versa, so you are trying to perform "circular dependency".

Quick search for node.js require circular dependencies gives a lot of stuff, for example :

> "Circular Dependencies in modules can be tricky, and hard to debug in
>   node.js. If module A requires('B') before it has finished setting up
>   it's exports, and then module B requires('A'), it will get back an
>   empty object instead what A may have intended to export. It makes
>   logical sense that if the export of A wasn't setup, requiring it in B
>   results in an empty export object. All the same, it can be a pain to
>   debug, and not inherently obvious to developers used to having those
>   circular dependencies handled automatically. Fortunately, there are
>   rather simple approaches to resolving the issue."

or 
[How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I didn't understand how to resolve this issue, I understand that I need to restructurate the code, but Is there any easy solution to solve that ?

Comment: I think the best way is to remove as many dependencies as you can. 
In perfect world your "rooms" and "user" should not have dependencies at all (except some basic mixins) but receive necessary data as arguments.
In JavaScript you don't have to include "class" definitions to access class methods, just provide the object and use its data.
Like you already done in "Listener: function(users) {"

Comment: Problem solved, thanks `:)` i've passed the modules in the function