# Unable to use Mongoose Object Methods from non-Mongoose Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Suppose we have a Mongoose object `Foo.js`.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Bar = require('/path/to/bar');

var Foo = mongoose.Schema({});

Foo.statics.hello = function() {
  console.log('hello from foo');
};

Foo.statics.useBar = function() {
  Bar.hello();
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Foo', Foo);
```

As well as a regular javascript object `Bar.js`.

```
var Foo = require('/path/to/foo');

var Bar = function() {};

Bar.hello = function() {
  console.log('hello from bar');
};

Bar.useFoo = function() {
  Foo.hello();
};


module.exports = Bar;
```

If we wanted to call methods in `Bar` from `Foo`, everything would be fine. Yet, if we wanted to call methods in `Foo` from `Bar`, we would receive an error.

```
app.use('/test', function(req, res, next) {

  var Foo = require('/path/to/foo');
  var Bar = require('/path/to/bar');

  Foo.hello();
  Bar.hello();

  Foo.useBar();
  Bar.useFoo();

});
```

The above yields:

```
hello from foo
hello from bar
hello from bar
TypeError: Foo.hello is not a function
```

Why does this happen?

Additionally, how do I create an object `Bar` that can call methods from `Foo`, but at the same time is not meant to be - and cannot be - persisted into mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is circular/cyclic dependencies in node.js. It gives you an empty object.

If you change `Bar.js` like this:

```
var Bar = function() {};
module.exports = Bar;

var Foo = require('/path/to/foo');

Bar.hello = function() {
  console.log('hello from bar');
};

Bar.useFoo = function() {
  Foo.hello();
};
```

and then swap the order in app.use to

```
var Bar = require('/path/to/bar');
var Foo = require('/path/to/foo');
```

it works for me.

Look at this answer for more information: [How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)