# Node.js, TypeError: xxx is not a function, in require'd file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files (for example).

**./database/user.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getUniqueByID: function(params){
        doSomething();
        return anUserObject;
    }
};
```

**./database/uperm.js**

```
var dbUser = require('./user.js');
module.exports = {
    createNew: function(params){
        dbUser.getUniqueByID(uid);
        doSomethingElse();
    }
};
```

Function `createNew()` from `uperm.js` always throws an exception:

```
.../uperm.js:123
dbUser.getUniqueByID(uid);
TypeError: dbUser.getUniqueByID is not a function
```

But, if i change `./database/uperm.js` to be:

```
module.exports = {
    createNew: function(params){
        require('./user.js').getUniqueByID(uid);
        doSomethingElse();
    }
};
```

Then `getUniqueByID()` from `user.js` is called by `createNew()` from `uperm.js`, without any exception.

But I don't whant to use `require('./user.js')` everywhere, instead of assigning it to `dbUser` variable.

What's wrong in case of using variable? Absolutely similar code in other files of my project seems to be ok.

Comment: Don't you have circular references between modules? It seems that you do.

Comment: Yes, that's true. file1 require's file2 and file2 require's file1 as well.

Comment: More than this... File1 depends on file1 and file 2 AND file2 depend on file1 and file2 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have circular dependencies, try to set properties of the `module.exports` instead of directly overwriting it:

```
var functions = {
   getUniqueByID: xxx
};

for(var key in functions) {
    module.exports[key] = functions[key];
}
```

(From the idea provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872988/2215166))

Comment: I've tryed var foos = { getUniqueByID: xxx }; module.exports = foos; ... But this does't help. Your solution works even if file1 depends on file1 and file2 and file 2 depends on file1 and file2 as well. Thank you again.