# NodeJS: Early require doesn't have access to object field

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm having a problem accessing a field in an object that is required/imported at the top of a file, the field is accessible however when importing the object again at a later point in the code.

---

I've made a little example to show what I mean: [[Execute code on CodingGround]](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=execute_nodejs_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMb1kxOUlfSkpmQXM)

**main.js**:

```
var ClassA = require('./ClassA');

ClassA.init();
```

**ClassA.js**:

```
var ClassB = require('./ClassB');

var ClassA = function() {};

ClassA.init = function() {
    // Define a variable in ClassA
    this.myVar = 'My Value';

    // Create an instance of ClassB, and try to print the defined variable
    var myClass = new ClassB();
    myClass.printMyVar();
};

module.exports = ClassA;
```

**ClassB.js**:

```
var ClassA = require('./ClassA');

var ClassB = function() {};

ClassB.prototype.printMyVar = function() {
    // Print the variable (not working)
    console.log('My Var: ' + ClassA.myVar);

    // Require ClassA again
    ClassA = require('./ClassA');

    // Print the variable again (working)
    console.log('My Var (again): ' + ClassA.myVar);
};

module.exports = ClassB;
```

I get the following output when `main.js` is executed:

```
My Var: undefined
My Var (again): My Value
```

---

Why does the first line show the variable is undefined, and why does it show the variable properly after requiring/importing the object again?

Is this caused by a circular dependency and if so, how can I avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the situation described [in the NodeJS modules "cycle" topic](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). The solution seems to be to *augment* the `exports` object rather than *replacing* it if circular dependencies are present.

Here's their example, modified to show that when `b` checks `a.done` *later*, it sees the correct value:

a.js:

```
console.log('a starting');
exports.done = false;
const b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in a, b.done = %j', b.done);
exports.done = true;
console.log('a done');
```

b.js:

```
console.log('b starting');
exports.done = false;
const a = require('./a.js');
console.log('in b, a.done = %j', a.done);
exports.done = true;
exports.check = function() {
    console.log('in b\'s check function, a.done = %j', a.done);
};
console.log('b done');
```

main.js:

```
console.log('main starting');
const a = require('./a.js');
const b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in main, a.done=%j, b.done=%j', a.done, b.done);
b.check();
```

The output is:

```
main starting
a starting
b starting
in b, a.done = false
b done
in a, b.done = true
a done
in main, a.done=true, b.done=true
in b's check function, a.done = true
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.

I assume you mean that I should _add_ functions/fields to the `module.exports` instead of fully replacing it with, for example `ClassA`. If that's the case, how would you define the constructor of the class?
I've asked a similar question in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js#comment64995389_10872988

Comment: @TimVisée: I think very much the way NodeJS itself does in some cases: A module defines a "namespace" if you will (the `exports` object), and individual classes are available as properties of that object rather than being top-level. E.g., like `fs.FSWatcher`, `fs.Stats`, etc. But they're not consistent: The events module replaces the `exports` object with `EventEmitter`. (I suspect ES2015's modules will solve this, but that could be wishful thinking on my part...)

Comment: Thank you.
I think I should try to avoid circular dependencies all together to keep everything _more modulair_.

Comment: @TimVisée: I'm sure that's the best course where possible. :-)