# Sequelize and Node.js: Issue with Module.Exports and Table Models

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am working on installing multiple databases in one server. To start this process, I am assigning one database in the index.js export object such that I will be able to add another DB as I build up the system. Below is the description of the issue.

When I run the server.js file, the .sync function for the database db1 syncs Table1 and Table2 and then begins listening on its port. Its clear the **server.js** file is receiving the `module.exports = db` through the `var db = require('./models')`. However in the file **models/Table1.js** the server throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Table1' of undefined`. I did check the console output for db in the **models/Table1.js** and it's empty, so its clear `module.exports = db` is not being accessed in this model.

**Can someone provide a solution to correct this issue?**

The partial code for the Table1.js model and other files listed above is below:

models/Table1.js

```
var db = require('./.')
[...]
var new_instance = db.db1.Table1.build({...})
```

server.js

```
var db = `require('./models')`
[...]
db.db1.sync(function(err) {});
```

models/index.js

```
var sq = new Sequelize(dbname, user, password, config);

db['db1'] = {
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize: sq,
    Table1: sq.import(__dirname + '/...'),
    Table2: sq.import(__dirname + '/...')
}
module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `module.exports = db` is being accessed, but you have created a cyclic dependency between `models/index.js` and `models/Table1.js` due to the fact that in the `Table1.js` model you require `index.js` file and in the `index.js` file you perform `sequelize.import()` call which performs `require(path)` to include the model definition, so in your case it calls `require('./Table1.js')` - there comes the cyclic dependency.

You should consider putting the `var new_instance = db.db1.Table1.build({...})` somewhere else in order to avoid this situation. Files with model definitions should be only used to create the Model definitions, try to avoid performing additional operations.

Take a look at this question - [How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js) to find out how you can deal with this kind of situations.

**EDIT**

According to your comment let's consider simple example with below structure

```
- script.js
- models
    - index.js
    - Table1.js
```

In `script.js`

```
var db = require('./models');
var new_instance = db.db1.Table1.build({...});
```

It can be done if you would **not** require the `script.js` inside any of the files placed inside `models` directory.

Comment: Can the code for the var new_instance = db.db1.Table1.build({...}) be placed in a script to save data into the DB?

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and through explanation. You know I had the impression until today, all DB save commands had to be preformed within the models. I was able to rewrite the logic of the system per your guidance and it worked. Awesome and Well Done!