# Returning find result to a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this function with which I want to find a employee first, ane store it to a variable 'a' and then pass it as an additional field for the aggregate:

```
module.exports.getEmployeeByIde = function(ide, callback){


    let a = Employee.findOne( {managerId: parseInt(ide) } );
    Employee.aggregate([
        { "$match": { id: parseInt(ide) } },
        { $limit: 1 },
        {
            $addFields: { "manager": a }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "employees",
                "localField": "id",
                "foreignField": "managerId",
                "as": "reports"
            }
            }]
    ).exec(callback);
}
```

but I get this error after trying to test it :

```
Error: cyclic dependency detected
    at serializeObject (C:\bookstore\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:296:33)
    at serializeInto (C:\bookstore\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:776:17)
```

Comment: See if this helps.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js

Comment: `findOne` doesn't return the found document, it provides it asynchronously to a callback that you need to provide.

Comment: so how can I populate my model with a field that uses a find method ?