# Graphql requiring module outside vs inside GraphQLObjectType

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

May be the title is not suitable with my problem but let me explain my scenario. 
I am working with Graphql schema.Here is my initial schema.js file https://github.com/sany2k8/graphql-udemy/blob/master/schema/schema.js

and it was working fine then I decided to split it into different small files e.g **root_query_type.js**, **mutation.js**, **user_type.js** and **company_type.js**. All the files are exported as module and required circularly. For example -

**user_type.js**

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const axios = require('axios');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt } = graphql;
//const CompanyType = require('./company_type'); // *this line causing error*


const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "User",
    fields: () => ({
        id:{ type: GraphQLString},
        firstName:{ type: GraphQLString},
        age:{ type: GraphQLInt},
        company :{
            type: require('./company_type'), // *this line fix the error*
            resolve(parentValue, args){
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${parentValue.companyId}`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
            }
        }
    })
});

module.exports = UserType;
```

**company_type.js**

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const axios = require('axios');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLList } = graphql;
const UserType = require('./user_type');


const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Company",
    fields: ()=> ({
        id: { type: GraphQLString},
        name: { type: GraphQLString},
        description: { type: GraphQLString},
        users:{
            type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
            resolve(parentValue, args){
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${parentValue.id}/users`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
            }
        }
    })
});

module.exports = CompanyType;
```

On my **user_type.js** file when I use `const CompanyType = require('./company_type');` at the top of file like this const UserType it is showing me below error message

> Error: User.company field type must be Output Type but got: [object
>   Object].

but if I comment out that line and put it directly then it works.

```
company :{
                type: require('./company_type'),
                resolve(parentValue, args){
                    return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/companies/${parentValue.companyId}`)
                        .then(res => res.data)
                }
            }
```

So basically my question is why it is not working with `const CompanyType = require('./company_type');` and but working with`type: require('./company_type')`. I could be a simple logical issue but It couldn't able to find.Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is not specific to GraphQL, but rather node in general. You have cyclic dependencies in your modules, which is causing your `require` statement inside `user_type.js` to resolve to an incomplete copy of `company_type.js`.

[According to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles), given two modules (`a.js` and `b.js`) that require each other:

> When `main.js` loads `a.js`, then `a.js` in turn loads `b.js`. At that point,
>   `b.js` tries to load `a.js`. In order to prevent an infinite loop, an
>   **unfinished copy** of the `a.js` exports object is returned to the `b.js`
>   module. `b.js` then finishes loading, and its `exports` object is provided
>   to the `a.js` module.

Moving the require statements inside your exports definition is one solution. You could also move your exports definition ***above*** your require calls to get the same affect. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js) looks at cyclic dependencies in more depth and also offers some alternative solutions.

As a side note, this is one of the reasons I would recommend moving away from declaring a GraphQL schema programatically. You can use `graphql-tools`'s [generate-schema](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html) to generate a schema from a GraphQL language document. This prevents you from dealings with potential cycle dependencies and results in a much more readable schema. You can modularize your schema easily as well; your type definitions are just strings and your resolvers are just objects -- both of which can easily be combined.

Comment: Yes I got it now. Thanks for the link reference.