# Error: Note.user field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object]

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am very new on graphql, i am playing with a simple case and can not make it work, the case is a simple one to many, a user has many notes and one note belongs to user.
My problem is with the "NoteType" I cannot return the "UserType", I can return the username of the User that create the Note but not the UserType

***Code (Important remove some fields)***

**NoteType**

When I uncomment de **user** I have the error ***Error: Note.user field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object].***

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLBoolean,
} from 'graphql';

import UserType from '../User/UserType';
import User from '../User/User';

const NoteType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Note',
  description: 'This represents a Note',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: (note) => note.id,
    },
    userId: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: (note) => note.userId,
    },
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (note) => note.note,
    },
    username: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (note) => (
        User
          .findOne({
            where: {
              id: note.userId,
            },
          }).then(user => user.username)
      ),
    },
    /* user: {  ***PROBLEM HERE!!***
      type: UserType,
      resolve: (note) => (
        User
          .findOne({
            where: {
              id: note.userId,
            },
          }).then(user => user)
      ),
    },*/
  }),
});

module.exports = NoteType;
```

**UserType**

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
} from 'graphql';

import NoteType from '../Note/NoteType';
import Note from '../Note/Note';

import LocationType from '../Location/LocationType';
import Location from '../Location/Location';

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'This represents a User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: (user) => user.id,
    },
    username: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (user) => user.username,
    },
    email: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (user) => user.email,
    },
    notes: {
      type: new GraphQLList(NoteType),
      resolve: (user) => (
        Note
          .findAll({
            where: {
              userId: user.id,
            },
          })
      ),
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = UserType;
```

**NoteQuery**

```
import {
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
} from 'graphql';

import NoteType from '../../models/Note/NoteType';
import Note from '../../models/Note/Note';

import UserType from '../../models/User/UserType';
import User from '../../models/User/User';

const noteQuery = {
  type: new GraphQLList(NoteType),
  args: {
    id: {
      name: 'id',
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    userId: {
      name: 'userId',
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    user: {
      name: 'user',
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    note: {
      name: 'note',
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    createdAt: {
      name: 'createdAt',
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      name: 'updatedAt',
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  },
  resolve: (user, args) => Note.findAll({ where: args }),
};

module.exports = noteQuery;
```

**UserQuery**

```
import {
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
} from 'graphql';

import UserType from '../../models/User/UserType';
import User from '../../models/User/User';

const userQuery = {
  users: {
    type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
    args: {
      id: {
        name: 'id',
        type: GraphQLInt,
      },
      username: {
        name: 'username',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      email: {
        name: 'email',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      createdAt: {
        name: 'createdAt',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        name: 'updatedAt',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
    },
    resolve: (user, args) => User.findAll({ where: args }),
  },
  user: {
    type: UserType,
    args: {
      id: {
        name: 'id',
        type: GraphQLInt,
      },
      username: {
        name: 'username',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      email: {
        name: 'email',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      createdAt: {
        name: 'createdAt',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        name: 'updatedAt',
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
    },
    resolve: (user, args) => User.findOne({ where: args }),
  },
};

module.exports = userQuery;
```

Any helps or tips thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a cyclic dependency issue. You're importing the User module into your Note module, while importing the Note module into your User module. Your resolver for the `user` field is looking for an instance of GraphQLObjectType, but it's only receiving an unfinished copy of the exported type.

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967015/graphql-requiring-module-outside-vs-inside-graphqlobjecttype/45969196#45969196) for a more thorough explanation and some workarounds.

However, I would suggest just declaring your schema with a string literal using [buildSchema](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildschema) and passing in your resolvers through the root object. Or using `graphql-tool`'s [makeExecutableSchema](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html), which is even easier. Either way, you'd be saving yourself the headache of dealing with cyclic dependencies, and make your schema more readable.