# How to set global variables for exported class methods in node.js

Tags: node.js, require

I have multiple different files broken out like so:

```
index.js
utils.js
ClassA/
  index.js
  base.js
```

utils contains a number of utility functions used everywhere. ClassA/index.js contains the constructor for ClassA as well as requires base.js, then exports ClassA. Base.js exports prototype methods for ClassA.  Here is basically what they look like:

```
//ClassA/index.js
function ClassA () {
  //constructor stuff
}
ClassA.prototype.constructor = ClassA;
require('./base')(ClassA);
module.exports = ClassA;

//ClassA/base.js
module.exports = ClassA => {
ClassA.prototype.aMethod = function () {
  log('hello');
}

//utils.js
module.exports = {
  log : function (logText) {
    //dostuff
  }
}
```

So my problem is that I cannot access the log function from within methods in `ClassA/base.js`.  If I set `const log = require('../utils').log` at the top of the file, it doesn't work.  It also doesn't work if I place that same line of code within the exports but outside of the method definitions, however it does work if I place it within the method itself (as expected, but this would mean replicating every require statement in any method in which it's needed). Is there any way around using this messy and repetitive route?

Comment: It's a circular dependency issue, possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js , but I will write an answer after I finish cooking :D

Comment: Ah you're right. I did some research and took the recommended path of refactoring to avoid it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with cyclic dependencies. I changed 'log' to be a method of ClassA and this resolved the issue.  Thanks to Francois P. for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to write an answer :)