# expressJS require a file which has route object from two different place does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

I am working on an expressJS project. I have a route file named `send_email.js`, and I want to use parts of this file from two different places. These places are `index.js` and `user.js`. 
So I added the following line for both of `index.js` and `users.js`:

```
const send_email = require("./send_mail");
```

But `user.js` is giving me an error because `send_email` is undefined. And then I just delete the same line from `index.js` and everything goes fine. I can reach send_mail in user.js, and it is what I expect.

Am I overlooking something about requiring files in expressJS? I can use this technique effectively in other projects. Are there expressJS specific things which cause this error?

I created same situation in another tiny project and its' codes like these:

---

// ------------------------index.js -----------------------

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

/* if coment this two line every thing goes fine */
const mylog = require("./deneme1").mylog;
mylog();
/* if coment this two line every thing goes fine */


const yourlog = require("./deneme2").yourlog;
const route = require("./deneme1").route;
console.log('route :', route);


yourlog();

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.send("OK!");
})


app.listen(3000, () => { "listening on "+3000});
```

---

// --------------deneme1.js -------------------------

```
const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();
const yourlog = require("./deneme2").yourlog;
console.log('yourlog mmm:', yourlog);

route.get("/deneme", function(req, res){
  mylog();
  res.send("OK!");
});

function mylog () {
  console.log("mylog in deneme1.js");
};

module.exports.route = route;
module.exports.mylog = mylog;
```

---

// ------------------deneme2.js-----------------

```
const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();

const mylog = require("./deneme1").mylog;
console.log('mylogxx :', mylog);

function yourlog(){
  console.log("yourlog deneme2");
  mylog();
  console.log("----");
}

module.exports.yourlog = yourlog;
```

---

`deneme1.js` and `deneme2.js` **require each other** and `express.js` **require both of `deneme1.js` and `deneme2.js`.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you export in your `send_mail.js` file? You should export whatever function you want to reuse . And use import wherever you need it. Instead of require.
For reference :[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: I think, it is about recursive require process. I have added some codes with same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that my problem is related "cyclic dependencies" between my route files. It is kind of design mistake. And there is a stackoverflow question/solution about it:
[how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)