# node.js require results undefined

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to node.js. I have the following code

```
module aws.js
  ....
  const awssvc = { dynamoQuery }
  module.exports = { awssvc }

module A.js
  const { awssvc } = require( ./index )
  ....
  module.export = { a }

module B.js
  const { awssvc } = require( ./index )
  ....
  module.export = { b }

index.js
const { awssvc } = require('./aws');
const { a } = require('./A');
const { b} = require('./B');

module.exports = { awssvc, a, b}
```

In A.js
  when executing `awssvc.dynamoQuery`, I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dynamoQuery' of undefined`.

What have I missed?

Or what should or should not go into index.js?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an equals sign after the deconstruction, `const { awssvc } require( ./index )` should be `const { awssvc } = require( ./index )`. Same thing goes for the `module.export { a }` should be `module.exports = { a }`

Comment: I have the `=` in my actual code. just edited the post. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have equals signs for the deconstruction assignments

`const { awssvc } require( ./index )` should be `const { awssvc } = require( ./index )`

Also, change `module.export { a }` to `module.exports = { a }`

It also looks like you're trying to import `awssvc` from the index.js file, it should be requiring from aws.js, So in module A.js `const { awssvc } = require(./index)` should be `const { awssvc } = require ('./aws.js')`

Comment: I changed in module A.js from `const { awssvc } = require(./index)` to `const { awssvc } = require ('./aws.js')`. and it worked. Can you help explain why I cannot require from index.js?

Comment: What you had before is a circular dependency, module A.js requires index, but index also requires A.js, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js) goes a little more in-depth about it