# Calling imported class' static method throws a TypeError error

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I'm trying to access a static method from an imported module I've created, but it results in throwing a TypeError error - stating that the method doesn't exist.

I've tried to export the modules differently. The method can be called if I'm using it as an instance method and not a static one, however it's not using anything which related to the class and I think it should be static.

The following static method:
(**Bot.js**)

```
const Bot = class Bot {
  static getCommandIndex(message) {
    if (!message.beginsWith('/')) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return message.split(' ');
  }
}

module.exports = Bot;
```

The module which attempts to use it:
(**BotUpdateHandler.js**)

```
const Bot = require('./Bot');
module.exports = class BotUpdateHandler {
  async handle(update) {
    const txt = update.msg.txt;
    const command = Bot.getCommandIndex(txt);
  }
}
```

I've already tried exporting and importing the modules like this:

```
// Exporting the module (Bot.js)
module.exports = { Bot };

// Importing the module (BotUpdateHandler.js)
const { Bot } = require('./Bot');
```

But that didn't work as well.

```
  TypeError: Bot.getCommandIndex is not a function
```

I'm using Node.js v10.16.0, it seems to work on browser-JavaScript when I checked it in the dev console (obviously though I wasn't doing any imports so I assume it's something to do with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Overview

So I've continued to research on the problem and tried figuring what exactly the issue was.

I'm coming from the world of C# and therefore I'm used to having `using` statements everywhere without a problem. However, with NodeJS, you cannot expect `require` to behave the same as the `using` statement as `require` - because `require` takes time to set up the exports and if you're having two modules depending on each other - that'll create something called **circular dependencies**.

### Solution

After some digging I've found [this](http://selfcontained.us/2012/05/08/node-js-circular-dependencies/) article and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js) question about circular dependencies. Eventually **it is best to avoid having circular dependencies in your code** like listed in the answers to the linked question above (having a top module which manages the code shared between the two modules).

However, there are also many nifty tricks to overcome this problem. The one I've used is using the `require` statement right before where I needed the static method to be.

```
module.exports = class BotUpdateHandler {
  handle(update) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    const Bot = require('./Bot');
    // code ....
    const txt = update.text;
    const command = Bot.getCommandIndex(txt);
  }
}
```

More over, I've found out you can check your code for circular dependencies (and many other useful things) using [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge).

Answer (score 0):

I think your module definition is ok, but what it's wrong is `BotUpdateHandler`:

```
    const Bot = require('./Bot');
    module.exports = class BotUpdateHandler {
      async handle(update) {
        const command = Bot.getCommandIndex(txt);
      }
    }
```

`Bot.getCommandIndex(txt)` is called with `txt` parameter and then the Bot class attempts to execute `beginsWith` method on it but `txt` is undefined (Probably you want to change by the var `update`).

So the method that doesn't exists is `beginsWith` on `txt`.

```
    const Bot = require('./Bot');
    module.exports = class BotUpdateHandler {
      async handle(update) {
        const command = Bot.getCommandIndex(update);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I missed on the following line (```javascript  const txt = update.msg.txt;```) - the error for sure states that ```getCommandIndex``` is not a function :(