# import variable from parent directory's file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a serverside script name server.js.
My directory structure is like this

[image]

I want to export a variable from server.js and trying to import it from users.js. But all I get is blank variable.

I have tried with a simple variable like

```
const hello="helloworld";
module.exports=hello;
```

But after printing the variable on users.js I get a "{}" on the page.

server.js code

```
var sql = require("mssql");

//SQL server config
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '*****',
    server: 'DESKTOP-45', 
    database: 'Testdb' 
};
// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }else{
      console.log("sql server connected");
  }

});

app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users',require('./routes/users'));

const request = new sql.Request();
module.exports=request;
```

users.js code

```
const sqlrequest = require('../server.js');
sqlrequest.query('select * from tbl_registration', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.send(recordset.recordset);       
        });
```

Comment: How user.js run ? when you run node server. I mean how user js and sever connected ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am updating the code again.

Comment: I have updated the code @shivam dhankani. Please have a look.

Comment: I got what the issue is plz see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js