# how to add custom function to express module

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to add a method
loadSiteSettings to express module

```
     In app.js


        var express = require('express');
        var path = require('path');
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');

        //Set up default monggose connection for mongo db
        var mongoDB = 'mongodb+srv://***:*****@cluste******j.mongodb.net/cms?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
        mongoose.connect(mongoDB,{useNewUrlParser: true});
        //Get the default connection
        var db = mongoose.connection;

        //Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
        db.on('error',console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));///????????

        var app = express();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

        app.loadSiteSettings = async function()
        { 
          let setting = await db.collection('settings').findOne();
          app.locals.siteSettings = setting;
        }

        app.loadSiteSettings();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        module.exports = app;
```

```
Index.Js for router

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = require('../app');
var util = require('util');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
///////////////////////////////////////////
router.get('/reloadSettings', function(req,res,next){
    app.loadSiteSettings();
})
///////////////////////////////////////

module.exports = router;
```

so problem lies here, when server start it calls app.loadSiteSettings() in app.js
but when i use route '/reloadSettings' it seems app is undefined in index.js

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with circular dependencies and module.exports.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428181/8727490) answer shows the same problem.

What's happening is `app.js` is required first and starts processing.  The important thing to understand is that a file **pauses** execution while requiring a new file.

So when `app.js` requires `./routes/index`, it has not finished processing, and has not reached `module.exports = app`.  This means that when your routes file requires `app.js`, it's requiring it in its current state, which is the default export `{}`.

Thankfully there's a very simple fix:

```
// can be imported and tested separately from the app
const loadSiteSettings = function() { 
    return db.collection('settings').findOne();
}


router.get('/reloadSettings', async function(req,res,next){
    let settings = await loadSiteSettings();
    req.app.locals.siteSettings = settings

    res.send(200); // signal the response is successful
})
```

[This](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) explains the issue in a lot more depth in case you're interested

Comment: I tried above like this
app.js

`const loadSiteSettings = async function()  
{ 
  let setting = await db.collection('settings').findOne();
  app.locals.siteSettings = setting;
}

loadSiteSettings();
module.exports = {app:app,loadSiteSettings:loadSiteSettings};`


again in route file index.js
`var a = require('../app');
var app = a.app;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.get('/reloadSettings', function(req,res,next){

//
a.loadSiteSettings();
})`

a is still undefined

Comment: I'm sorry, When I originally posted it I missed a critical line: ```req.app.locals = settings```.  See the post for the updated code! Because app is available on the ```req``` object, you do not need to require it anywhere in your routes/controllers.

Comment: But what i was trying to achieve is load setting in app initial boot, and if i change settings then i can reload app.locals.settings with the changes instead of passing in every request

Comment: ```req.app``` and ```app``` both point to the same object.  ```req.app``` is provided as a convenience for faster access, and removes the need for an import.  Your route ```/reloadSettings``` already receives the ```req``` object, so this is definitely a more "express" way of handling this.