# Worried about circular references in EcmaScript 2015 modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, webpack-encore

I'm using webpack with [.splitEntryChunks()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/split-chunks.html) enabled.

I had this crazy idea to split all my logic into separate files:

```
|utils
|- animations.js
|- controls.js
|- debug.js
|- dialogs.js
|- events.js
|- index.js
|- layout.manager.js
|- regex.js
|- settings.js
|- translator.js
```

That looks great to me. But now I have a couple of page-specific js files (called managers) that need parts of these utils.

For example:

```
// /managers/forumManager.js
import Translator from '../utils/translator';
import Controls from '../utils/controls';
import Dialog, { LoadingDialog, Toast } from '../utils/dialogs'
```

There are more managers that work in a similar way. Now whenever I build my project I end up with some big vendors~*.js files (1~2mb in size).
I can't find a way to reduce the file sizes, so I decided to go for `/utils/index.js` as a hub for all utils.

```
// /utils/index.js
import Translator from './translator';
import Settings from './settings';
import Animations from './animations';
import Events from "./events";
import Controls from './controls';
import Dialogs, { LoadingDialog, Toast } from './dialogs';
import RegexUtils from './regex';

export { Translator, Settings, Animations, Events, Controls, Dialogs, LoadingDialog, Toast, RegexUtils };
```

But `Dialogs` needs access to a couple of utils, so:

```
// /utils/dialogs.js
import { Translator, RegexUtil, Animation, Events, Controls } from './index';
```

This reduces the number `vendors~*.js` files, but this doesn't feel right.
There's a suggested solution on [this site](https://railsware.com/blog/how-to-analyze-circular-dependencies-in-es6/) down by Resolving problematic dependencies (passing dependencies via the constructor). But I don't like that idea at all.

I'm hoping someone with a better understanding of ES6 can help me with this

Comment: interesting post on [cyclic dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js/24428181) - maybe worth a read ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix pfew... thanks. I understand why it would be a problem, But it just feels like a big limitation and it's so natural to do it this way o_O. Guess I'm gonna need to rethink how I organize my code then

Comment: always try to keep the compiled code in mind: When A requires B and B requires A - how would the compiler know how to construct the logic to be executed? _"De kat bijt in zijn eigen staart"_

Comment: @iLuvLogix Haha, domme kat!