# how to use a global variable when it takes a value in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, global-variables

I have a file called app.js:

```
let id = 0;
const Func = require('./func.js');
Func.myFunc();
console.log(id);


module.exports = {
     id 
};
```

Also I have another file called func.js:

```
const App = require('./app.js');
var myFunc = () => {
 App.id = 100;
}


module.exports = {
    myFunc
};
```

But `console.log(id)` returns: 0

Comment: One requires the other, and the other requires the one. Looks like you are on track for strange loop if this even works at all... Rethink your logic :)

Comment: Two files can't `require()` each other (well they *can*, but not in the way you expect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is termed circular dependencies. It is generally frowned upon and there is no allowed instance where this may be required. You're better off creating a third file that will use both of them...

Read this to have a better understanding:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

[How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)

Comment: You're better off creating a third file that will use both of them. Fantastic, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add another log like:

```
 // app.js ...
 console.log(module.exports);
 module.exports = { id };
 console.log(id);
```

to see that your code does work somehow, in the way that `module.exports` has an id property set, but you override that afterwards. Also the property of the export object has nothing todo with the `id` variable (well, the later gets copied into the first) so `console.log` will never log 100.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your piece of code:

- the circular dependency
- module.exports.id is not the same object as the variable id in app.js

In order to solve the first problem, you should create a third file where the variable will be declared and other modules will use that.

Now, to illustrate the second problem, look at the following.

```js
// testModule.js
let variable = 0;

function get_variable() {
    return variable;
}

module.exports = {variable, get_variable};
```

```js
// app.js
const testModule = require('./testModule.js');

testModule.variable = 1234;
console.log(testModule.variable);       // will print '1234'
console.log(testModule.get_variable()); // will print '0'
```

This little misunderstanding of modules, could lead to subtle nasty bugs. I consider that the best practice to solve this would be not to export the 'variable' property directly, but having getter/setter functions in the module, almost like transforming it into a class-like thing.

```js
// testModule.js
let variable = 0;

function get_variable() {
    return variable;
}

function set_variable(value) {
    variable = value;
}

module.exports = {get_variable, set_variable};
```