# Why am I having Node.js local module importing inconsistencies?

Tags: node.js

I'm really suffering here due to some awful inconsistencies in importing/exporting modules in Node.js.

It's easier to see:

```js
//game.js

const {Player} = require("./player");

{...}

console.log(Player); //outputs undefined


//player.js

class Player {
    constructor(client, host = false) {
        this.properties = {...client};
        this.host = host;

        this.hand = [];
    }
    {...}
}

module.exports = {Player};
```

This may seem fine but here's the strangest part. Inside another file, `deck.js`, I export in the exact same way. And it gets correctly recognized in `game.js`.

```js
//game.js

const {Deck} = require("./deck");

console.log(Deck); //outputs "[Function: Deck]"


//deck.js

class Deck {
    constructor() {
        this.deck = [...compressed_cards];

        this.shuffle();
    }
    {...}
}

module.exports = {Deck};
```

These are both local files, as you can see. I can import deck.js just fine but not player.js, despite the exact same methodologies. I've tried `module.exports.Player = Player`, I've directly set `module.exports.Player = class Player {...}`, it just won't seem to work. To whoever figures this out and makes me look like an idiot, thanks.

Oh, and to add to my confusion, I can import `player.js` in other files *outside* of the folder just fine. But not inside. *Why.* And of course, all of my other files can access each other in the *exact same* way without any issues.

File structure looks like this:

[image: this]

Comment: player.js and game.js are in the same folder?

Comment: They definitely are

Comment: I suspect you have circular dependencies. That means player.js might require game.js or deck.js, such that when you draw lines between files that require each other, you will see a full circle.

More about circular/cyclic dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js

Comment: Yeah, I have player.js requiring an object from game.js; I didn't know it was an issue but I'll see how to fix that if it is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason could be that you have circular dependencies. That means `player.js` might require `game.js` or `deck.js`, such that when you draw lines between files that require each other, you will see a full circle. The suggestion is to restructure your dependencies to avoid such dependency structure.

More about circular/cyclic dependencies is discussed here: [How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)

Comment: That was my issue, I moved the object I was requiring into my player file and it worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) you should be able to import / export a class like this:

```
//game.js

const Player = require("./player");


//player.js

class Player {...}

module.exports = Player;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me; same result. Player is undefined. What's just so confusing is that it works fine for `deck.js` but not `player.js`.

Comment: Maybe check your file names & folder structure again?

Comment: They're both in the same folder