# Weird error with node js: TypeError X not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, typeerror, node-modules

Anyone know why this is happening?

I have a pretty complex system so to simplify it we have this code:

profile_manager.js

```
const Profile = require('./profile');

class ProfileManager {
  doThing() {
    const prf = new Profile("Lemon", "ade");
  }
}
const prfManager = new ProfileManager();
module.exports = prfManager;
```

profile.js

```
class Profile {
  constructor(arg0, arg1) {
    //do thing
  }
}

module.exports = Profile;
```

index.js

```
const prfManager = require('./profile_manager');
prfManager.doThing();
```

Once .doThing() is called, I get a TypeError saying that "Profile is not a constructor".

HOWEVER... When I change profile_manager.js to the following code below, it works perfectly. No TypeError.

```
class ProfileManager {
  doThing() {
    const Profile = require('./profile');
    const prf = new Profile("Lemon", "ade");
  }
}
const prfManager = new ProfileManager();
module.exports = prfManager;
```

I even console.logged the prf object and it works the way I want it to. Why does it only work when I move the "const Profile = require('./profile');" within the method but when I put it at the top of the module, it does not want to work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, node v12.10.0. Anyone who upvoted care to enlighten me?

Comment: Yes, till now I have copy-pasted your code in NodeJs v 10, and it worked fine. Now I will try to use Node v 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that profile.js had an instance of profile_manager.js or something like that

This post talks more about it [How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)