# NodeJS require() can't access to module and return no function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to import my select module in my organization class. My select module as lot of function and i need to access in my organization class.

But the problem is when I try to require my select module from my organization class I have empty object returned. So when I try to use select.somefunction() I have "somefunction is not function". I have another class : User placed in same directory. And when I import select like that :
`const select = require("../interfaces/database/select")`.
I have eatch function in select constant...

here you can see my project structure :

```
├───interfaces
│   ├───database
│   │       delete.js
│   │       insert.js
│   │       select.js
│   │       update.js
│   │
│   └───restAPI
│           scAPI.js
│
├───models
│       Organization.js
│       User.js
│
└───util
        logger.js
        PostgresHelper.js
```

so here is my select module:

```js
const log = require("../../util/logger")
const db = require("../../util/PostgresHelper")
const User = require("../../models/User")
const Organization = require("../../models/Organization")

module.exports = {
    async getUserFromDiscordID(discordID){
        //some code
    },
    async getUserFromHandle(handle){
        //some code
    },
    async isRegisterFromDiscordID(discordID){
        //some code
    },
    async isRegisterFromHandle(handle){
        //some code
    },
    async getUserLangFromUserID(UserID){
        //some code
    },
    async isOrganizationRegisterFromSID(organizationSID){
        //some code
    },
    async getOrganizationFromSID(organizationSID) {
        //some code
    },
    async getLangFromID(langIDs){
        //some code
    },
    async getLangIDs(lang) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

and here is my organization class :

```js
const select = require("../interfaces/database/select")
const scapi = require("../interfaces/restAPI/scAPI")


class Organization {
    /**
     * @param organizationSID
     * @return {Promise<Organization|void>}
     */
    static async tryGetOrganizationFromSID(organizationSID){
        //let select = require("../interfaces/database/select"); -> when I do that it work but I don't want that
        console.log(select)//return empty object
        if (await select.isOrganizationRegisterFromSID(organizationSID)){
            return await select.getOrganizationFromSID(organizationSID)
        }else{
            let organizationData = await scapi.getOrganization(organizationSID)
            if (organizationData){
                return organizationData
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Organization
```

here is the user class code :

```
const select = require('../interfaces/database/select')//Here the import work and I have eatch function
const scapi = require("../interfaces/restAPI/scAPI")

class User {

    constructor() {
        this.discordID = null
        this.country =null
        this.region = null
        this.organizationSID = null
        this.organizationRank = null
        this.bio = null
        this.lang = []
    }
    /**
     * @param {String} discordID
     * @return User
     */
    static async tryGetUserFromDiscord(discordID){
        if (await select.isRegisterFromDiscordID(discordID)){
            return await select.getUserFromDiscordID(discordID)
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param {String} handle
     * @return User
     */
    static async tryGetUserFromHandle(handle){
        let returnUser = new User()
        if (await select.isRegisterFromHandle(handle)){
            return await select.getUserFromHandle(handle)
        }else {
            returnUser = await scapi.getUser(handle)
            if(returnUser){
                return returnUser
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = User
```

Comment: Can you put the User code too in here?

Comment: yes I just add it in question ^^

Comment: Try to add a constructor the Organization, and put console.log(select) in there.

Comment: I can see a lot of cyclic dependency here. Not the way to go. Why are you referencing **select** from the models?

Comment: @BahaEddineAyadi I have try that but because I don't call select request my object is never generated. I have try to create new one in static methode but that don't have work I don't have see console.log

Comment: @KunalKukreja I referencing select from the models because the static method use database request to self generate object.

Comment: Cyclic dependency indicates a problem in your design. You should revisit your application design and check if this is really necessary. Only if it is absolutely necessary, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js/14098262#14098262) might help you deal with it

Comment: KunalKukreja but why that have work for the user class ?

Comment: @KunalKukreja exactly, this is what threw me off. The same thing worked for the User class. Maybe it works, but it's not consistent.

Comment: So revisiting your application design could do the trick for you @MrSolarius

Comment: thanks everyone I going to rework my application. When I fine solution I goging to insert here