# Calling a class from another class in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, constructor

Consider the first file -> one.js where i import another class from another file called two.js

One.js

```
const twoService = require('./two')
const twoObj = new twoService()
Class First{
constructor(){}

helperOne(){
twoObj.helperTwo()
}
}
```

Now consider the second file , two.js , where i'm importing the class from the first file -> one.js

Two.js

```
const oneService = require('./one')
const oneObj = new oneService()
Class Second{
constructor(){}

helperTwo(){
oneObj.helperOne()
}
}
```

So simple , I have two classes which has dependent functions of each other , so when I call the One.js file and invoke the First class , i'm getting the error as **TypeError: oneService is not a constructor**

How It can be solved ???

Comment: That's called circular dependency

Comment: Hi @ThomasSablik , how it can be solved ?? Its a legacy code , so I have to change it with least code changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)