# getRandomInt is not a function when exporting to another file with exports.getRandomInt = getRandomInt

Tags: node.js, module.exports

so I'm trying to keep my code clean. To do so I used VS code's built-in code refactoring "move to a new file". As always it couldn't be that easy so everything is not working. When I'm trying to use this method in my Game class, I get an error saying `getRandomInt is not a function`. I've seen a dozen StackOverflow threads about this, although none of them could fix my problem. Then I thought it may be just an individual problem, so here I am. Stuck with the same problem for two days...

Game.js:

```js
const { getRandomInt } = require("./index.js");

class Game {
    /**
     *
     * @param {Discord.Message} message
     * Passes the message object for the playerId that will be the game Id
     */
    constructor(message) {
        this.cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
        this.playerId = message.author.id;
        this.dealerCards = [];
        this.playerCards = [];
        this.message = message;
    }

    start() {
        console.log(this.cards);
        for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
            this.playerCards.push(this.cards[getRandomInt(1, this.cards.length)]); 
            //There's an error saying that getRandomInt is not a function
            this.dealerCards.push(this.cards[getRandomInt(1, this.cards.length)]);

        }
        console.log(this.playerCards);
        console.log(this.dealerCards);
        this.message.channel.send(`Dealer cards: ${this.dealerCards[0]} ${this.dealerCards[1]}\nPlayer cards ${this.playerCards[0]} ${this.playerCards[1]}`);

    }

    hit() {
        this.playerCards.push(this.cards[getRandomInt(1, this.cards.length)]);

    }
}
exports.Game = Game;
```

index.js (a bit cut down, but it shouldn't make a difference):

```js
const { Game } = require("./Game.js");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
exports.getRandomInt = getRandomInt;
```

Is it that hard? It's built into VS code's refactoring system, so I think something is on me.

Comment: Your title says `exports.getRandomInt = getRandomInt` which would be correct, your file says `module.exports = new getRandomInt;` which is wrong.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was trying out many things and none of them worked out, I'll change that so it doesn't get anyone confused. But it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular dependency issue. I don't know why you need to import `Game.js` in your `index.js` file but removing it will fix the problem. If you still want to use `Game.js` in your `index.js`, there're some approaches for you:

- Make an empty module export. Ex: put `exports.Game = function(){};` and `exports.getRandomInt = function(){};` at the beginning of modules. It depends on your logic that this approach can fix your problem, you better provide more detail about your code to know your real issue.
- Refactor your code.

More info:

[How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: Well I didn't. VS code's refactoring system did. All I did was that I clicked on the Game class, then refactoring, and then move to a new file, it wasn't working. Could you explain it on my example?

Comment: [index.js](https://pastebin.com/xQts1y2B) and [Game.js](https://pastebin.com/U33NZJ6X)

Comment: if you don't know what it is, or what it does to your code, why did you use it?

Comment: Well hell, I do know what it does, I wrote it myself. The only copied thing is the getRandomInt function, which I was too lazy to write. That shouldn't be the problem though. And I haven't said that I don't know what my code does. And the reason is that I wanted for it to look... "slick?". Just it's prettier when it isn't in one giantic file (made that mistake before)

Comment: okay, keep it straight: keep the line `const { Game } = require("./Game.js");` as is, move the rest of code in `index.js` to another file (such as `getRandomInt.js`), change the `require` file location in `Game.js` to point to the new file.

Comment: It works! I moved the getRandomInt to another file and somehow everything started working haha. Thank you I've been stuck at this for 2 days.