# NodeJS require issue

Tags: node.js

I have nodeJS express setup having the following structure -

```
-app.js
-routes
---user_router.js
---org_router.js
-controller
---user.js
---organization.js
-model
---userOrganization.js
```

Now, my `app.js` has the routes declarations one after another, and in my both routes their specific controller's get() methods are called

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
// ---- Some required code ----

const user_router = require('./routes/user_router');
const org_router = require('./routes/org_router');

app.use('/user_router', user_router);
app.use('/org_router', org_router);

// ---- Some required code ----
```

**Routes**

> user_router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const userCtrl = require('../../controllers/user');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getUser', (req, res) => {
    userCtrl.getUsers()
      .then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error' });
      });
});
module.exports = router;
```

> org_router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const orgCtrl = require('../../controllers/organization');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getOrg', (req, res) => {
  orgCtrl.getOrg()
      .then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error' });
      });
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Controllers**

> user

```
const userOrganizations = require('../models/userOrganizations.js');
const getUsers = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userOrganizations.getOrgWiseUser()
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
});

module.exports = {
  getUsers,
};
```

> Organizations

```
const userOrganizations = require('../models/userOrganizations.js');
const getOrg = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userOrganizations.getUserWiseOrg()
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
});

module.exports = {
  getOrg,
};
```

**Models**

> userOrganizations

```
const getUsers = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(['testUser1', 'testUser2', 'testUser3']);
});

const getOrg = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(['testOrg1', 'testOrg2', 'testOrg3']);
});

module.exports = {
  getUsers,
  getOrg,
};
```

Now, there is plenty of other code resides in my repo including routes, controller, models, and all others, etc.
Now when I call the specific method of `org_router` I am facing the error -

> userOrganizations.getUserWiseOrg is not a function

If I rewrite controller `organization.js` like below then it is working(Just moving model declaration from global to local in function)

```
const getOrg = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const userOrganizations = require('../models/userOrganizations.js');
  userOrganizations.getUserWiseOrg()
  .then(resolve)
  .catch(reject);
});
```

I am not understanding why it is not allowing me to declare the model globally(Why the globally required package is not accessible)

There is one more case if I comment out the `require()` statement from the `user` Controller then my `organization` controller's global require() statement works well and also it is accessible inside the function as well.

My node version is - `v12.20.0`

What can be the issue? any guess????

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js
This might help.

Comment: I don't see any definition for a function `getUserWiseOrg` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think you have a circular dependency. Removing a require from another controller or moving the require from global scope to local scope are two possible solutions to circular dependency problems. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14098262