# Recursive modules return empty element when required

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, module, require

I currently have a program structured like the minimal example below. I have object `foo` which
has method `addColor`, which requires module `bar`.

`bar` requires `baz` and passes the parameter `color`.

`baz` requires `foo` to edit a property from `foo` (`addColor` must add a color to `foo.colors`)

However inside `baz`: `foo` returns `{}` and the following error occures.

```
foo.colors.push(color);
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I imagine this is an issue with module recursion and cannot find a work-around to this problem without possibly restructuring my program.

index.js

```js
const foo = require('./foo');

console.log(foo);
// { colors: [ 'red', 'green' ], addColor: [Function (anonymous)] }

foo.addColor('blue');
```

foo.js

```js
module.exports = {
  colors: ['red', 'green'],
  addColor: require('./bar')
}
```

bar.js

```js
const baz = require('./baz');
module.exports = color => {
  baz(color);
};
```

baz.js

```js
const foo = require('./foo');
module.exports = color => {
  console.log(foo); // {}

  foo.colors.push(color);
  /*
    foo.colors.push(color);
               ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
  */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a cycle in your dependency graph. That's likely to cause problems. See this question for some ideas on how to resolve the problem: [How to deal with cyclic dependencies in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I ended up making `foo` a global environment variable. I'll mark my question as a duplicate to the thread you've linked.