# How do node.js circular dependencies work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner so I am probably missing something obvious here, but something about this doesn't make sense to me.
I have a function I want to call from my main code that references a variable that is stored and changed often in the main code.
I have greatly simplified it in this example code:

test1.js:

```
const { doStuff } = require("./test2.js");

let x = 1;

setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Test1 :", x);
    x++;
    doStuff();
}, 1000);

module.exports = { x };
```

test2.js:

```
module.exports = {
    doStuff(){
        let { x } = require("./test1.js");
        console.log("Test2 :", x);
    },
};
```

So I expect that when "doStuff()" requires x, it would find the **current** value of x, but in the log, I get:

```
Test1: 1
Test2: 1
Test1: 2
Test2: 1
Test1: 3
Test2: 1
Test1: 4
Test2: 1
```

Which shows that test2.js is pulling the original value of x.
I've read that it is requiring the cached value, so you need to use `delete require.cache[require.resolve("./test1.js")];` before you require it, but when I do that, I get much weirder behavior where the amount of logs doubles each second, and test2.js still doesn't get the correct value.
Is my only option to make a global variable? I've heard they are a bad idea and I had planned on having quite a few very big objects required this way.

Comment: Export a state object. `const state = {x: 1};` and then `state.x++;` and  `module.exports = { state };`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I see, so requiring a module causes the code in the body root to run. Of course it would.  
I see what you mean about the function, but when I try that I get `Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findx' of module exports inside circular dependency`
If I wanted that method, I would have to put the variable and the getter function in a separate module and require it in both files, which can easily be done. Thanks

Comment: Key point is that objects are "by reference" and primitives (such as numbers) are "by value". Assigning an object to a variable copies its reference, so multiple variables can contain the same object, whereas assigning a number makes a copy of the current value. Compare `a = {x: 1}; b = a; a.x++; console.log(b);` and `a = 1; b = a; a++; console.log(b);`. That's why exporting an object works, and exporting a primitive doesn't.

Comment: In general node.js does not support circular dependency. Do not create circular dependencies in your projects. However, references can be circular. You can have objects that have members that point to something that points to that object. You just cannot do it with `require()` or `import`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The module system in Node.js does not support circular dependency and this is by design. In your original case you have accidentally tricked Node into a circular dependency situation by lazily requiring test1 (you only require it once the function is called).

You need to design your code so that dependencies only happen in one direction. Pass the thing that the other module need normally using functions instead of dependencies.

test1.js:

```
const { registerX, doStuff } = require("./test2.js");

let x = { value: 1 }; // need something that is not
                      // a number or string since we 
                      // need a reference (pointer)
                      // instead of a value

registerX(x); // we pass x to test2 module

setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Test1 :", x.value);
    x.value++;
    doStuff();
}, 1000);
```

test2.js:

```
let x = {};

function registerX (otherX) {
    x = otherX;
}

function doStuff(){
    console.log("Test2 :", x.value);
}

module.exports = {
    registerX,
    doStuff
};
```

Comment: Note that javascript's saving grace is that type is dynamic. However you will find yourself in trouble again if you use Typescript because TYPES cannot be passed like objects. So if you end up with circular type dependency in Typescript you are making a mistake. There is however a work-around that can sort of fix it: use interfaces and have both things depend on the same interface. OR, use polymorphism and have two things inherit from the same class or interface - a class/interface can depend on itself

Comment: I believed this is in fact incorrect and it does support circular dependencies? Though `node.js` has low tolerability towards it. The former argument could be supported by their [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Comment: @hokwanhung is correct; this answer should be removed. I've added a new answer with relevant links.

Answer (score 0):

@slebetman is not correct though his answer is marked correct. This topic has a few nuances that are already covered in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js).

Specifically, [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872988/5033601)

More formally, [this is the node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Edit:

I believe your specific issue is explicitly assigning the `module.exports =` directive rather than just adding to it.